# 'Connection refused' with sockets

Tags: python, sockets

Client The code has been written in  Python.

**Client**

```
import socket

host = '192.168.0.118'
#host = ''
port  = 5560

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host,port))

while True:
    command = input("Enter your command")
    if command == 'EXIT':
        s.send(str.ecode(command))
        break
    elif command == 'KILL':
        s.send(str.encode(command))
        break
    s.send(str.encode(command))
    reply = s.recv(1024)
    print(reply.decode('utf-8'))
s.close()
```

**Server**

```
import socket

host = ''
port = 5560
storedValue = "You man I done"
def setupServer():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("yes Created")
    try:
        s.bind((host,port))
    except socket.error as msg:
        print(msg)
    print("socket bind complet")
    return s
def setupConnection():
    s.listen(1)
    conn,address = s.accept()
    print("done connection: " + address[0] + ":" + str(adress[1]))
    return conn

def GET():
    reply = storedValue
    return reply

def REPEAT (dataMessage):
    reply = dataMessage[1]
    return reply

def dataTransfer(conn):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        dataMessage = data.split(' ', 1)
        command = dataMessage[0]
        if command == 'GET':
            reply = GET()
        elif command == 'Repeat':
            reply = REPEAT(dataMessage)
        elif  command == 'EXIT':
             print("our client has left us")
             break            
        elif command == 'KILL':
            print("Shut down")
            s.close()
            break
        else:
           reply = 'Unknown Command'
           conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
           print("Data has been sent")
    conn.close()#

s =  setupServer()

while True:
    try:
        conn = setupConnection()
        dataTransfer(conn)
    except:
        break
```

Error I got this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cookieClient.py", line 8, in <module>
    s.connect((host,port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: please include your code in the question

Comment: The error message says "Connection refused". Seems like you are trying to connect to a socket that isn't listening.

Comment: @M omid In the post the imgur [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvk7x.jpg) of the code is not shown. Paste the essentials of the real code into your modified question and format it by selecting it and press ctrl-k. It should do the job.

Comment: Are you sure the host at '192.168.0.118' is listening? Could it have been assigned a new ip?

Comment: Run from command-line the server and use an editor for client. Or vice-versa.. and use some print statements in combi with `sys.stdout.flush()` underneath it to see what is going on during "debugging".

Comment: Are the server and client on the same host?

Comment: Does the host filter the port?

Comment: @CongMa they are on the same network......